# setState() callback argument returned a Future

Tags: flutter, http, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am new in flutter and stuck with this issue. Any one help me
setState() callback argument returned a Future.  The setState() method on _SingupPageState#7bfa9 was called with a closure or method that returned a Future. Maybe it is marked as "async".
setState(() async {

```
        String url = 'http://192.168.43.91:8000/api/signup';
        var json = jsonEncode({
          "name": name.text.toString(),
          "email": email.text.toString(),
          "password": password.text.toString(),
        });
        Response response = await post(url,
            headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, body: json);
       // Map<String, dynamic> user = jsonDecode(response.body);
        if(response.statusCode==200){
          print('success');
        }
        else{
          print('not success');
        }

      }
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

you should write something like that:

```
onTap:() async{

 setState((){
   //what you want to do  } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are trying to make post request, this kind of method's return type should be future, try to first get the result by defining then use the response statusCode to use setState i mean :

in case of having a `RaisedButton` Widget your code should look like that :

```
onTap : () async {
await //call your http,
setSatet((){
//somecode base on http result
})
```